# How to remove the files connected to a column in a table in AWS

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tables created using the crawler over parquet files. I want to remove all the data (in S3) contained in a column in one of the tables. How should I do that?

I tried ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column but did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to Athena when you mention ALTER TABLE and DROP. Athena is a query engine for fetching and joining data from s3 after it has been catalogued (which in your case is by the crawler). The data on s3 is immutable meaning that Athena cannot alter or delete data on s3; in order to change the data in s3, you will have to create new data and delete the old data.

In your case, I see two convenient ways of doing what you ask.

1. Create a new table with a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` [(CTAS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) query. Here you can specify the s3 location that the data for the table should be stored. Afterwards, you can drop the old table to remove the metadata from Glue and manually delete the old files from s3.
2. If you don't necessarily need to delete the data from s3, you could create a [view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html) on top of the old table which does not include the column you want to remove.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have only a question if I create a table with Athena, will it be written as a series of parquet files or only 1 parquet file

Comment: @thisisme you can specify the number of files using the `bucket_count` parameter. See example here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/